# Trying to find two different text nodes from a descendant

Tags: xpath

Someone decided to make a site as unfriendly as possible by intention so I'm trying what I can to have our scraper still get to where it should.

```
<div class="issueDetails">
 <div class="issueTitle ng-binding" style="">FANCY UNIQUE TEXT dd.MM.yyyy</div>
 <a>COMPLETELY DIFFERENT TEXT</a>
```

I've left out the unnecessary details here, but I'm trying to find a match within the site through XPATH (can't use anything else for this) that will find something which fulfils *both* conditions, FANCY UNIQUE TEXT dd.MM.yyyy ***as well as** COMPLETELY DIFFERENT TEXT.

I've tried my luck with `//div[@class='issueDetails']/descendant::*[contains(text(), 'FANCY UNIQUE TEXT dd.MM.yyyy') and contains (text(), 'COMPLETELY DIFFERENT TEXT')]`

but it contains the erroneous logic that both unique things I need are in the same thing.

The first, FANCY UNIQUE TEXT, is the unique identifier for where I want to go. The second, COMPLETELY DIFFERENT TEXT, is what I need the scraper to click on to actually head to that specific one. So an XPath that finds both despite them being different descendants is necessary.

Comment: My experience is that some newcomers to Stack Overflow believe that if they beg and plead hard enough, they will get what they need. In practice, some readers find this practice coercive, and tend to think that it is not kind to try to manipulate volunteers into helping more than they have time or energy for. I have downvoted for now, and will retract that vote if you can rename your user to something other than "beggingforhelphere".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for :

```
//div[@class="issueDetails"]/*[contains(.,"COMPLETELY DIFFERENT TEXT") or translate(substring(.,string-length(.)-9,10),"123456789","000000000")="00.00.0000" and contains(.,'FANCY UNIQUE TEXT')]
```

It will return the 2 elements respecting your conditions : `div` and `a`.
`Translate`, `substring-length` and `substring` functions are used to check if a date pattern is present in the div element.

[image: Date]

EDIT : Check if the parent+child contains the text you're looking for, then get the childs with :

```
//div[@class='issueDetails'][contains(.,"FANCY UNIQUE TEXT dd.MM.yyyy") and contains(.,"COMPLETELY DIFFERENT TEXT")]/*[contains(.,"FANCY UNIQUE TEXT dd.MM.yyyy") or contains(.,"COMPLETELY DIFFERENT TEXT")]
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! The date can easily be solved by our scraper with ${util.formatToday('yyyyMMdd')}. My issue is that the two child nodes are different child nodes - a div and an a and XPATH 1.0, which is the only one supported by browsers, seems to fight tooth and nail to not let me combine the XPATHs to search for different nodes I'm looking for into one result. On a related note, some people have claimed that a pipe | between the two things I look for will merge them - turns out, nope. It acts as an "or".
I've got a logic error in the original question with the "and contains", sorry for that

Comment: OK. I've updated my answer with another solution. The XPath expression will test the content of the parent and his childs elements. If the two texts are found in this unique string, we get the child elements which respect your conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much! It *almost* does what I need, now it finds two results (first one focusing on the text, second one on the link) but I can solve that with a [2] at the end to force it to use the 2nd result. Merci beaucoup, please look at the Mona Lisa and stay away from youth punks!